# GridsearchCV with Exception

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm trying `GridsearchCV` but I would like to have some exceptions in `param grid`. Here's my grid search code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model(input_dim=25, activation='relu', units=100, optimizer = 'adam', init='he_normal', dropout_rate=0.33):

       model = Sequential()
       model.add(Dense(input_dim=input_dim,
                       units=units, 
                       kernel_initializer=init, 
                       activation=activation))
       model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
       model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='sigmoid'))
       model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
       return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

#lr = [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001] # [x/100 for x in range(1, 10)] #learning rate for optimizer
units = [int(train_X.shape[1]/2), train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[1]*2, train_X.shape[1]*3]
batch_size = [32, 64, 128, 256]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
epochs = [50, 100, 200]
init = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']
activation = ['softmax', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'hard_sigmoid', 'linear']
dropout_rate = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

cv = [(slice(None), slice(None))]

param_grid = dict(units=units, batch_size=batch_size, optimizer=optimizer, epochs=epochs, 
                  init=init, activation=activation, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

grid = GridSearchCV(cv=cv, estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_data=(valid_X, valid_y))
```

when I runt his code, even though `KerasClassifier` has the parameter of `epochs=10`, the grid never runs 10 epochs but runs for `[50, 100, 200]` which I provided in the grid. It's like the `epochs=10` was overwritten.

Now what I want to do is, I would like to use different `activation functions` in first layer but keep `Sigmoid` in the output layer. What I'm afraid is, will the `activation='sigmoid'` parameter be overwritten by my `activation = ['softmax', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'hard_sigmoid', 'linear']` parameter that will come from grid?

I hope this one makes more sense to you.

Comment: Can you add your grid search CV code, please? Otherwise it's difficult to suggest how to help.

Comment: @AlexL Added. Thanks.

Comment: double check your version of Keras, maybe update. And where exactly is the error coming from? Is it from the Keras model, the GridSearchCV, ...?

Comment: @anki Solved the error. It was the keyword "neurons" was illegal. I replaced it with units and problem solved. But my main question remains :)

Comment: @anki Keras is up to date. I edited the code, this one is working.

Comment: @iso_9001_, but you specify your epochs as ```epochs = [50, 100, 200]```, the ```n_jobs=1``` parameter is only how [many jobs should run in parallel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), not your epochs.

Comment: @anki there's nothing in my post about `n_jobs.` I wrote `epochs=1` maybe you misread.

Comment: @iso_9001_, below the line of ```optimizer = [...]``` and above the ```init = [...]``` is a line with ```epochs = [...]```. When I copy your code and run it with random data, and change this line to ```epochs = [1]``` it works exactly as you desire

Comment: @anki I think you misunderstood my question and it's due to my post being unclear. I will edit it from scracth to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @AlexL I have changed the description entirely and added the code. Can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with KerasClassifier, but I think you're attempting to accomplish too much without understanding what's going on. With the parameters you're currently testing, you'll be running 21,504 iterations for one CV fold! Assuming your dataset isn't completely trivial and takes at least 2 seconds to fit, you're looking at 12 hours of Grid Search right there, *at least*. It's been known for a while now that Grid Search isn't the most effective CV strategy for expensive functions like a neural net. Random Search and Bayesian optimization have proven to be more efficient and capable of giving comparable or better results. *However*, as I stated, this is getting too complicated!

I recommend reading up on all those activation functions and optimizers and learning rates and such and narrowing your search space. Do as much tailoring to your data before starting CV. Moreover, it's good practice to implement some sort of folding CV, such as K-fold or stratified k-fold. Read up on these too, they're important.

If you're still looking to implement this, you might just find it easier to manually make two `for` loops: an outer one to iterate over each parameter and an inner loop to iterate over each hyper-parameter. Within the inner most loop, you could build, compile, and fit your model right there without having to use sklearn or KerasClassifier at all (which is hiding a lot of important details). You could also take this opportunity to learn more about functional vs. sequential Keras, the former arguably is the more powerful.

I apologize for the non-answer, I just think you may be causing yourself more headache than necessary! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the head-up. I know the hyperparameter space is too big but those were just copy-paste. I'm going to narrow down the space. I also can do this with for loop but I prefer to let libraries handle most of the job. BTW I'm not using CV in order to lower the calculation time, too.

Comment: If you're actually concerned about calculation time, you should narrow the parameter space and add KFold CV. You'll get more out of an intensive latter than an intensive former. In reality, you're not letting sklearn handle any significant amount of work. Since you're not parallelizing, two for loops would be nearly identical.

Comment: Calculation time is important but not my main concern. I'll use parallelizing but my laptop gives an error for n_jobs so I had to cancel it. All I'm trying to do is to be sure to use activation function list for hidden layer but make the output layer's function be constant.